# typescript casting return from database to class

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, casting, angular-promise

I'm trying to return array of specific type from my provider in an ionic app using ionic 3.20.0 (Angular 5.2.10 && typescript ~2.6.2)

In my provider I have this

```
export class vwOrderList {
    OrderSheetId: number;
    Pickup: DateTime;
    Orders: number;
    Items: number;
    Total: number;
    BilledAmt: number;
    get Done(): boolean {
        return this.Total == this.BilledAmt;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class OrderSheetsProvider {

    getOrdersList() {
        return new Promise<Array<vwOrderList>>(resolve => {
            this.http.get('http://*****.elasticbeanstalk.com/odata/vwOrderLists').subscribe(data => {
                resolve(<Array<vwOrderList>>data["value"]);
            }, err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The odata service returns an object in which the data is contained in the `"value"` property and looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context":"http://******.elasticbeanstalk.com/odata/$metadata#vwOrderLists","value":[
    {
      "OrderSheetId":1589,"Pickup":"2016-09-26T16:00:00Z","Orders":89,"Items":116,"Total":2349.54,"BilledAmt":2349.54
    },{
      "OrderSheetId":1921,"Pickup":"2016-12-14T10:00:00Z","Orders":142,"Items":204,"Total":3387.22,"BilledAmt":3387.22
    },{ ... more
```

In the page that uses this info I have this:

```
export class OrderListPage {
    dataSource: vwOrderList[];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public ordersProvider: OrderSheetsProvider) {
        this.getOrders();
    }
    getOrders() {
        this.ordersProvider.getOrdersList()
            .then(data => {
                this.dataSource = data;
            })
    }
}
```

At first I tried casting the result in the page that uses the return. I tried using various things

```
// of course I didn't try these all at once, just one variation at a time
this.dataSource = data as vwOrderList[];
this.dataSource = data as Array<vwOrderList>;
this.dataSource = <Array<vwOrderList>>data;
```

I couldn't get any of these to work, so instead I modified the promise to include the return type `Promise<Array<vwOrderList>>`. This makes more sense anyway because anywhere I want to use the vwOrderList type, it should be that type. But that doesn't seem to be working either.

```
resolve(data["value"] as vwOrderList[]);
resolve(data["value"] as <Array<vwOrderList>>);
resolve(data["value"] as Array<vwOrderList>);
resolve(<Array<vwOrderList>>data["value"]);
resolve(Array<vwOrderList>data["value"]);
resolve(<Array<vwOrderList>>(data["value"]));
```

The data comes through but as an array of object rather than the vwOrderList type, of course, doesn't have the getter for the 'Done' method.

What do I do to return an array of the vwOrderList type from my provider?

TIA, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this just isn't going to work this way and, even if it did, it wouldn't be helpful anyway. Typescript is a design-time convenience for humans to keep the data right during development and help with intellisense. Even if it did the casting during development, the transpiling into JavaScript would remove the casting and the objects wouldn't wind up being the type I wanted.

I could make it work by creating an array of the needed type and creating instances of them in a foreach with the elements that returned from the DB. When I tried this out it worked ok (I got the correct types) and it was fast enough.

```
getOrdersList() {
    return new Promise<Array<vwOrderList>>(resolve => {
        this.http.get('http://*****.elasticbeanstalk.com/odata/vwOrderLists').subscribe(data => {
            var result = vwOrderList[];
            foreach (var element in data['value']) {
                result.push(new vwOrderList(element)); // add a constructor to vwOrderList that takes the object
            }
            resolve(result);
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```

This didn't really solve the ultimate goal which was to be able to write a single function that returned the appropriate type regardless of the class. I was hoping to turn it into < Array < T > > eventually. Typescript just doesn't work that way.

Mike